# Reading JSON content from Android

Tags: android, json, curl

I'm having issue with reading JSON from URL.

For desktop applications I have been using "curl" to read content from URL.

i.e. `curl -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://example.com/abc.py/data'`

I am using following code to do the same in Android App but it is not working.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

Comment: are you trying to parse the JSON in your android app?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons it might not work, one reasons is that it is actually inputStream that's returned by getContent, here's a snippet of working code from my app

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


...


private static String getInputStreamAsString(Context ctxt, InputStream is)
{
    byte[] sBuffer = new byte[512];
    ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Read response into a buffered stream
    int readBytes = 0;
    try
    {
        while ((readBytes = is.read(sBuffer)) != -1)
        {
            content.write(sBuffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Util.e(ctxt, TAG, Util.fmt(e));
    }
    return new String(content.toByteArray());
}


public static test() {
    HttpClient client = DefaultHttpClient()
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);;
    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
    String str = getInputStreamAsString(ctxt, response.getEntity().getContent());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies.

The error was occurring because I didn't set Internet permission within manifest so it wasn't able to connect to the URL.

It works now :)